# Application Error - Heroku / Ruby on Rails / Soundcloud Social Download App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, soundcloud

Afternoon all,

I've been slaving at this for 2 days trying to fix the issue and get even the basic template for the Soundcloud Social Download app online. Even after following all the steps it is still pulling errors...I'm at the end of my tether and I'd grateful of some help. I've included the log below:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\justbegoodsingle>heroku open
Opening http://pure-meadow-7119.heroku.com/

C:\justbegoodsingle>heroku logs
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `
block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
new'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
block in <main>'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<
main>'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<mai
n>'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load
'
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-09-15T12:23:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-15T12:23:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p
7946 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-15T12:23:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-15T12:23:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-09-15T12:24:51+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET pure-me
adow-7119.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-09-15T12:24:51+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 83.217.112.230 - - [15/Sep/2011:05:24:5
1 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Ge
cko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" pure-meadow-7119.heroku.com
2011-09-15T12:24:54+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 83.217.112.230 - - [15/Sep/2011:05:24:5
4 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; r
v:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" pure-meadow-7119.heroku.com
2011-09-15T12:24:54+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET pure-me
adow-7119.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-09-15T12:33:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-09-15T12:33:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-15T12:33:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p
15429 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bu
ndler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': You have already acti
vated rack 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.0.1. Consider using bundle ex
ec. (Gem::LoadError)
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/rub

2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/preinitializer.rb:16:in
 `<top (required)>'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:28:in `preiniti
alize'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:124:in `<top (r
equired)>'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-09-15T12:33:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-09-15T12:34:23+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET pure-me
adow-7119.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-09-15T12:34:23+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET pure-me
adow-7119.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue=

2011-09-15T12:46:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-09-15T12:46:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-15T12:46:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p
14227 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bu
ndler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': You have already acti
vated rack 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.0.1. Consider using bundle ex
ec. (Gem::LoadError)
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/preinitializer.rb:16:in
 `<top (required)>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:28:in `preiniti
alize'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:124:in `<top (r
equired)>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:3:in `<t
op (required)>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29:in `
new'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29:in `
block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `
block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
new'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
block in <main>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<
main>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load
'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<mai
n>'
2011-09-15T12:46:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-15T12:46:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-09-15T12:51:24+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 83.217.112.230 - - [15/Sep/2011:05:51:2
4 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Ge
cko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" pure-meadow-7119.heroku.com
2011-09-15T12:51:26+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET pure-me
adow-7119.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-09-15T12:51:26+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 83.217.112.230 - - [15/Sep/2011:05:51:2
6 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; r
v:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" pure-meadow-7119.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" You have already activated rack 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.0.1. Consider using bundle ex
ec. (Gem::LoadError)"

You need to change your Gemfile to use the same version of rack as heroku does. You can probably run

bundle update rack

You seem to be running ruby 1.9.2 on the server, are you doing the same locally? There's different stacks on heroku http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the end but downgrading my version of Ruby to 1.8.7 then running the app on a different stack on Heroku using the "Heroku create --stack" command.